# How can I track /index.cfm to / only...as google analytics is tracing these as two links

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-analytics

Even after setting up default page in view setting of google analytics I want when some user opens /index.cfm it should redirext to /.

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCompatibility2 On  
RepeatLimit 200  
RewriteBase  
[hash] unsupported directive: [ISAPI_Rewrite]  

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^website_name\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^/products.html$ http\://www.website_name.com/products.cfm [L,R=301]   

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.cfm?$ [NC]   
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.cfm?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]   

ErrorDocument 404 /404.cfm   

ErrorDocument 500 / http://www.website_name.com
```